# How did Isildur possess the power to deny the Oathbreakers the Gift of Man?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

When the Oathbreakers did not come to Isildur's aid as they had sworn to do, Isildur cursed them to be bound to Middle-Earth, unable to leave even after death until they fulfil their oaths to his line.

The Gift of Man is Illuvatar's blessing to grant to all mankind, good or evil. How is Isildur able to deny Illuvatar's gift to the Oathbreakers simply because of some earthly oath made to a royal Númenorean who possesses no divine power?

Answer (score 5):

Only Ilúvatar has the power to give, or to deny, his gift. But oaths done in the name of Ilúvatar may have consequences beyond the power of the Valar. Fëanor's oath, as an example. Ilúvatar's will needn't to be perceived by men or elves clearly; his designs may appear in the history just as "Destiny" or "Doom". "Bilbo was destined to find the Ring".

There's no text evidence that the Dead Men of Dunharrow made his allegiance to Isildur in the name of Ilúvatar, but the consequences of his perjury say so. Isildur's power is not what doomed them, but "Destiny".

Comment: That's a reasonable explanation. It'll be great if there are sources to back it up in Isildur's case though. With magic being an inherent part of Elven existence, you never know with these half Elves.

Comment: Just a small remark, Bilbo found the Ring, not Frodo. Frodo may have been the one destined to bring it to Mount Doom.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, yes. Did I write Bilbo? My fault. By the way, when I wrote it I was thinking about this LOTR quote, where Gandalf says to Frodo: "Behind that there was something else at work, beyond any design of the Ring-maker. I can put it no plainer than by saying that Bilbo was meant to find the Ring, and not by its maker. In which case you also were meant to have it. And that may be an encouraging thought." (1.2.116)

Comment: @Ginasius lol, you mixed them up in the comment again. You can edit your post though.

Comment: I believe it is confirmed in letters that this was done with the direct intervention of eru.